# Toggle ClearType (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, cleartype

Is there a tool or something which can quickly enable or disable ClearType without going through the windows 7 ClearType-configuration dialog every time?

I need this because I have to make screenshots quite often and screenshots look blurred when ClearType is activated. And when ClearType is disabled everything looks blurred on my screen, so I usually enable it again after taking a screenshot.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676768/enable-disable-cleartype-in-windows7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest either of these options :

- Enable/disable Cleartype using a tool called [Cleartype Switch](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/enable-disable-window-7-cleartype-text-anti-aliasing-with-cleartype-switch/)
- Using [cttune](https://web.archive.org/web/20170506063214/http://www.technixupdate.com/enable-disable-clear-type-in-windows-7/) by running the command `C:\Windows\System32\cttune.exe`

Comment: Cleartype Switch is exaclty what I was looking for.

Comment: Your second suggestion is just running the control panel applet - so not saving the while multi-dialog sequence. Anyway, I was actually looking for the progname of that applet, so +1 for that. You can type `cttune` in the search box of the start menu and the applet will be found.

Comment: The link has been expired. So, I've updated it to the  **WebArchive** version.