# Can you make things SMALLER in the display?

Tags: windows-10

**Update:**  My question is indeed a duplicate of [Scale < 100% on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1328938/scale-100-on-windows-10) (I did search before posting, but hadn't found this question).  Sadly, the answer there does not seem to work for recent builds of Windows 10.  Thanks anyhow, @music2myear.

---

**Original:** 
Under Settings → System → Display, there's an option called “Scale and layout”: “Change the size of text, apps, and other items,” it says. It defaults to 100% (“Recommended”!), but offers 125%, 150%, and 175%. I suppose those are for visually-impaired people. Is there any way to make text, apps, and other items **smaller**?

I have two 27" 1920x1080 monitors (about 82 dpi).  Windows's fonts are huge on this display. Now, I realize that these aren't the highest-resolution monitors available.  But I bought them because I wanted to see *more* stuff, not because I wanted to see *bigger* stuff. The line spacing in Explorer, Settings, and other programs is large— like 20 pixels. I could easily live with half of that, thus allowing me to fit four times as much stuff on my desktop. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scale < 100% on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1328938/scale-100-on-windows-10)

Comment: You'll also want to read these posts, the answers AND the comments. Doing this can break things: https://superuser.com/questions/80151/how-to-setup-custom-dpi-below-100-on-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

I have also been looking for how to accomplish this as I find these large icons and text to be ***EXTREMELY ANNOYIING!***
So, after researching everything, I was unable to find a REAL answer to "Where in the Windows 10, Settings, Do I Resize My Screen to Less Than 100% or Just Plain 100" question... However; I kind of found a small hack to be able to at least accomplish this outside of the Microsoft Windows Settings. It is going to annoy all of the old timers like myself that have been doing this in Word Documents, Browsers, and other apps throughout the years.

Please press and hold the [Windows Flag] button (located in the lower left and/or right of your keyboard in the same row as your spacebar *normally*) and then tap or press the letter [M] (on your keyboard's bottom row) to minimize all open windows (pretty much EVERYTHING on your screen) to the desktop of your computer. Then, once you are on the desktop (This way you may see what you are doing to the size of most everything viewable on your computer's monitor). Press and hold the [CTRL] key, while on the mouse scroll wheel [UP] or [DOWN] in the direction you require the size to go.

For me, it took scrolling *'down'* to reduce the size of EVERYTHING that made Windows more appealing again.

Break Down of the Steps Used to Reduce the Windows 10, Screen, Icon Size Setting

  **First Step -**
  Minimize all Open Windows on your screen;
    +
    *On Physical Keyboard*
    Press the [Winows Flag] Key,
    + Quiclkly Tap or Press the Letter [M] Key,

  **Second Step -**
  Adjust Screen Size Setting;
    +
    *Now, Again On Your Physical Keyboard*
    Press and Hold the [Ctrl] Key
    + Then on the
    *'Scroll Wheel of your Mouse'*
    , scroll up or down to increase or decrease sizes,

Hopefully this helps everyone that is frustrated on another item removed by our illustrious benefactor... Microsoft!

Good Hunting To Everyone

Brian

Comment: This makes no sense, you're just resizing what's inside of the applications i.e. the text not the application or windows itself

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks. Do you know a way to change the old windows theme parameters, like icon spacing, border width etc ?