# Gain space on screen

Tags: display, resolution

I had a 23 inch monitor running at a resolution of 1920 x 1080 where I could properly fit two windows on the screen. In order to gain more space on the screen I bought a 31 inch monitor which also ran at a resolution of 1920 x 1080.

The new screen size is bigger and seems to fit three windows properly at the same time, but it turns out that it just scaled the 23 inches.  I only see things a bit bigger now, but I didn't gain any more space as I had previously assumed.

[image]

Is there any way to rescale the screen to make things smaller and gain more space?

[It is a full screenshot of the 23 inches and 31 inches screen, there is no difference, everything is bigger in the 31 inches screen so i didn't gain any space in the bigger screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqVPm.png)

Comment: Computers doesn't have the concept of "fit windows properly". You can resize 10 windows and place them next to each other on a 10" (640*480) monitor or show just one window on a 40" 4k monitor. Please describe your requirements with more details.

Comment: @MátéJuhász i have added a link to a picture to provide more details

Comment: The picture was there already before my comment, I still don't understand how the computer should know your desired setting. Computers doesn't know "physical space" they know only pixels.

Comment: I’m going to go out on a limb here and refer you to Microsoft’s [Powertoys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) utility.  In particular, take a look at Fancy Zones.

Comment: Hi Walter, can you indicate if running at a higher resolution is possible? If not, consider this: your 23" screen has 1920 pixels in width, your 31" has 1920 pixels in width. The only difference is that the pixel of the 31" are larger than the 23" pixels. So a window of 960px wide will cover the same amount of pixels on both screen, but will have a large physical size on the 31" screen.

Comment: Why is it not possible to resize the windows to a 640px width? That will fit three windows on a 1920px wide screen.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke so i need a bigger screen but that screen has to support bigger resolution in order to gain more physical space, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest solution. Does this 31" screen not support higher resolutions? Alternatively you can look [at DPI scaling of less than 100%](https://superuser.com/a/1328941/141595).

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke no, this 31'' screen supports until 1920x1080. I guess it would be better to have two 23'' screens than having one 23'' and one 31'' because a 31'' screen with 2560*1440 costs way too much.

Comment: I think it's a bit more comfortable to have a 23" screen on my desk, then a 31" screen, especially as the ["ideal" viewing distance of a 31" screen is rather large](https://www.the-home-cinema-guide.com/images/tv-size-viewing-distance.png). But if your goal is to watch movies from your couch on that 31" screen I would say it's fine.