# Windows 10 dpi scaling with 27 inch Display 1440

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, dpi

The monitor I have is a Dell p2720dc - 27-inch display. Recently I have been using it with all 3 Operating systems. On Windows, although I have set the resolution to 2560 x 1440 pixels I find it does not create more desktop "real estate" that other operating systems Linux & MacOS do.

For example the youtube website gives a nice comparison see (all 3 share the 1440p resolution on a 27 inch display):

- [MacOS Desktop Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qBNP.jpg)
- [Linux Desktop Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeQMG.jpg)
- [Windows Desktop Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFZEy.jpg)

There is no scaling performed on Windows see [display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nynTF.png), however, things seem to be a little big. I have tried this solution mentioned by [music2myear](https://superuser.com/a/1328941/1671016) to lower the DPI below 100% however it seems that Windows 10 has disabled this option. This 27-inch display serves as my an extended display to my laptop screen (1600x900), yet things in scale comparison seem smaller there. The laptop I have is an Asus N55SL with a 1600x900 resolution 15.5-inch display. There is an Intel HD Graphics 3000 & NVIDIA GeForce GT 635M Cards.

Is there any way I can decrease the size of everything on the 1440p 27-inch display so that things have the same scale as macOS & Linux? If so can somebody point me to some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to leave this answer for anybody running into the same problem of having an old laptop with Nvidia GT XXXX Style GPU with HDMI output. After coming back and digging some more, I was lucky to find a solution in Nvidia Control Panel. It looks like inside [Nvidia Control Panel > Display > Change Resolution](https://i.imgur.com/hMzrGrS.png), there is a customize button that allows to create a [custom resolution](https://i.imgur.com/gytRen6.png). This experimental feature allows you to set [any custom resolution](https://i.imgur.com/S2S07c7.png) I assume within hardware bounds. Once set the [new custom resolution will be created](https://i.imgur.com/YZodar2.png) and stored.

Now I'm able [to get the resolution](https://i.imgur.com/V34xsgq.png) I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You may have figured this out or moved on by now.

According to specs, you have set the resolution of the monitor incorrectly. Your display settings shows 2048 x 1080, but the monitor should be capable of QHD (2560x1440). You might need to install a driver to allow windows to see the monitor as QHD.

Also, press start, type "make everything bigger", and select the "Make Everything Bigger" under "System Settings". Make sure the slider for "Make text bigger" is all the way to the left. I had changed this on my high resolution laptop and it was scaling everything on my other screens as well.

I edited this post after initially posting because I noticed your resolution settings were wrong.

Comment: So I did a bit of investigating after pulling my laptop off the shelf and blowing off dust. The laptop I have is ASUS N55SL, yes it is old. When I posted I connected it using VGA which of course supports a max resolution of VGA is 2048×1536 (whereas I need 2560x1440). I tried the HDMI port. For some reason, it does not go beyond 1080p.  ChatGPT says HDMI 1.4 and above can support 1440p, but older versions might not. Maybe this laptop doesn't have HDMI 1.4. Maybe it's a hardware limitation. I can't find HDMI information about this machine.