# Some fonts are difficult to read in Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, while MSIE works fine

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, opera

I noticed that on my computer, some fonts are difficult to read in Google  Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. However, Microsoft Internet Explorer works fine.

For example, on https://www.overleaf.com/13693764frfpzxpydsgd#/52976444/, I see:

[image]

Instead, I would expect the text to be more readable, e.g.:

[image]

What could be the issue?

I use Google Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I don't have this issue on Chrome on my MacBook Pro.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://redd.it/7zvcpo

Comment: Some thoughts: font smoothing (Advanced System Settings, Performance, Settings, Smooth edges of screen fonts); [ClearType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) ([cttune.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/297455/toggle-cleartype-windows-7) to turn on/off and tune); [ClearType Switch](http://karpolan.com/software/cleartype-switch/) for both. Maybe the graphics driver is interfering, and a different (newer? older?) one fixes this. Interesting that MSIE behaves differently from all other browsers.

Comment: With the Overleaf pdf I would think it's a problem related to TeX fonts, so asking the LaTeX stackexchange might give help. I had the same issue with LaTeX-made pdfs until I changed some font setting in them. But from your recent post on travel (which led me here), I also guess the problem is wider than that.

Comment: @Dronir thanks yes I first noticed it on overleaf, then one day it became wider.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It may even be two different and possibly even unrelated problems then.

Comment: @Dronir could be, I'm in the dark

Comment: Intriguing! This has been going on for almost three years without a solution? Are you still using Windows 7? Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: @magma Some of my computers are on Windows 7, sometimes VM, sometimes not. That's correct, almost three years without a solution.

Comment: If it's a laptop then a forum that covers different laptop manufacturers..If a desktop then you could try changing graphics card.